# Black screen ao simular aplicativo no xcode Iphone 7 PLUS

Tags: ionic, xcode

Estou tentando simular meu aplicativo gerado com Ionic no xcode para tirar as printsscreens necessárias para enviar para a revisão. Quando eu seleciono o iPhone 5/6 ele abre normalmente, porem quando seleciono do iPhone 6 Plus pra frente (que são os que possui tela de 5.5 inch, o simulador fica preto e não inicia o ios)
Existe alguma configuração adicional que precisa ser feita para simular nestes dispositivos? Obrigado.

Comment: Você está simulando todos com a mesma versão do IOS?

Comment: @Renata acho que sim, é no deployment target que especifica a versão do iOS?

Comment: Estou baixando a ultima versão do iOS simulator (11.3), ele automaticamente vai aplicar esse iOS quando eu simular pelo iPhone 7?

Comment: Tentei com a nova versão do iOS 11.3 e 11.4, ambas ainda levam em black screen

Comment: No iPhone 5/6, você simulou com essa mesma versão do IOS?

Comment: Sim, essa mesma versão de iOS funciona no iPhone 5, porem no iPhone 6 Plus pra frente que eu preciso simular pra tirar as screens, fica na tela preta

Answer (score 0):

O xcode precisa que você configure o Launch Screen para todos os aparelhos, para cada iphone existe uma tamanho diferente de Launch Screen[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]